# Calculate the textbox value based on the value of combobox ? ( wpf )

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textbox

I have a small program, because I'm new, my program is to bring data from sql sever to textbox via combobox option and use the value shown in that textbox to calculate the +
I have made it to the step of putting up the data, now thanks to you to help me with the value calculation in the textbox, thank you for your help.
xaml code :

```xml
<Window x:Class="comboboxapp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:comboboxapp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SimpleMath x:Key="MyFriends"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Label Content="code" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,52,0,0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Height="23"/>
        <Label Content="pieces" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,126,0,0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Height="23"/>
        <Label Content="layers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,196,0,0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Height="30"/>
        <Label Content="production pieces" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="0,278,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Height="25"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtcode" 
                 Text="{Binding Txtcode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="124,52,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtpieces" 
                 Text="{Binding Txtpieces, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
                 Margin="124,133,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtlayers" 
                 Text="{Binding Txtlayers,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
                 Margin="124,203,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtproductionpieces" 
                 Text="{Binding Txtproductionpieces,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="124,280,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyFriends}}" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="319" Height="36" SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtseccond" 
                 Text="{Binding Txtseccond,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
                 Margin="124,345,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
        <Label Content="seccond" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,345,0,0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Height="23"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding A, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,133,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="248"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding No1,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="426,210,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace comboboxapp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public SimpleMath Formular { get; set; }
        public object SelectedValue { get; private set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Formular = new SimpleMath()
            {
                Txtcode = 0,
                Txtpieces = 0,
                Txtlayers = 0,
                Txtproductionpieces = 0,
                Txtseccond = 0,

            };
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Formular;
            Fillcombobox();
        }
        private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

        }
        public void Fillcombobox()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LEAN-22\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=LUAT;Integrated Security=True");

            string sql = " select * from comboboxnew ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataReader myreader;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string sname = myreader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
        public class SimpleMath : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private int no1;

            public int No1
            {
                get { return no1; }
                set
                {
                    no1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("No1");
                    OnPropertyChanged("A");
                }
            }
            private int txtcode;

            public int Txtcode
            {
                get { return txtcode; }
                set
                {
                    txtcode = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Txtcode");
                    OnPropertyChanged("A");
                }
            }
            private int txtpieces;

            public int Txtpieces
            {
                get { return txtpieces; }
                set
                {
                    txtpieces = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Txtcode");
                    OnPropertyChanged("A");
                }
            }
            private int txtlayers;

            public int Txtlayers
            {
                get { return txtlayers; }
                set
                {
                    txtlayers = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Txtlayers");
                    OnPropertyChanged("A");
                }
            }
            private int txtproductionpieces;

            public int Txtproductionpieces
            {
                get { return txtproductionpieces; }
                set
                {
                    txtproductionpieces = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Txtproductionpieces");
                    OnPropertyChanged("A");
                }
            }
            private int txtseccond;

            public int Txtseccond
            {
                get { return txtseccond; }
                set
                {
                    txtseccond = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Txtseccond");
                    OnPropertyChanged("A");
                }
            }
            public double A => No1;

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName()] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LEAN-22\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=LUAT;Integrated Security=True");
            //  string sql = " select * from comboboxnew where code = '" + comboBox1.Text+ "';";
            string sql = " select * from comboboxnew where code = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + 
"';";
            //Console.WriteLine(comboBox1.Text);
            //MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con); 
            SqlDataReader myreader; 
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string code = myreader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                    string pieces = myreader.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                    string layers = myreader.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                    string productionpieces = myreader.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                    string seccond = myreader.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                     txtcode.Text = code;
                    //txtcode.Text =SelectedValue;
                    txtpieces.Text = pieces;
                      //txtpieces.Text = "New value";
                    txtlayers.Text = layers;
                       //txtlayers.Text = "New value";
                    txtproductionpieces.Text = productionpieces;
                     //txtproductionpieces.Text = "New value";
                    txtseccond.Text = seccond;
                    //txtseccond.Text = "New value";

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to sum those values and show it in that `TextBox`?

Comment: Example: if i want caculator 1 value Textbox take from 5 textbox and show this textbox ? textbox =( textbox1 - textbox2) /textbox3 ?

Comment: public double A => No1;    
can't do it

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you simply want to sum those five values into the `TextBox`, right?

If so, you can do that multiple ways...

One:
Have a property in the `SimpleMath` class that is the sum of the other values, and bind that to the `TextBox`. You would have to update the sum property whenever any of those five other ones updates.

Two:
You could use the `IMultiValueConverter` to sum the values without having any more properties in the `SimpleMath` class. It's done like this:

You create a class that implements the `IMultiValueConverter` inteface

```
public class SumConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Cast<int>()?.Sum()?.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And use it in XAML like this

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <local:SumConverter x:Key="SumConverter"/>
    </TextBox.Resources>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SumConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="OtherTextBox1" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="OtherTextBox2" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="OtherTextBox3" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="OtherTextBox4" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="OtherTextBox5" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</Control>
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

I've made a test project to show you the full code for both of my suggested solutions, here it is:

**Solution one**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace StackOverflowTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new SimpleMath();
        }
    }

    public class SimpleMath : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _numberOne;
        public int NumberOne
        {
            get => _numberOne;
            set
            {
                _numberOne = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                CalculateSum();
            }
        }

        private int _numberTwo;
        public int NumberTwo
        {
            get => _numberTwo;
            set
            {
                _numberTwo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                CalculateSum();
            }
        }

        private int _numberThree;
        public int NumberThree
        {
            get => _numberThree;
            set
            {
                _numberThree = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                CalculateSum();
            }
        }

        private int _numberSum;
        public int NumberSum
        {
            get => _numberSum;
            set
            {
                _numberSum = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void CalculateSum()
        {
            NumberSum = NumberOne + NumberTwo + NumberThree;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName()] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtOne" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding NumberOne}" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtTwo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding NumberTwo}" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtThree" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding NumberThree}" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NumberSum}" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Solution two**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflowTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new SimpleMath();
        }
    }

    public class SimpleMath : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _numberOne;
        public int NumberOne
        {
            get => _numberOne;
            set
            {
                _numberOne = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private int _numberTwo;
        public int NumberTwo
        {
            get => _numberTwo;
            set
            {
                _numberTwo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private int _numberThree;
        public int NumberThree
        {
            get => _numberThree;
            set
            {
                _numberThree = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName()] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class SumConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var numbers = new List<int>();
            foreach (var item in values)
            {
                if(item is string stringValue)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        numbers.Add(System.Convert.ToInt32(stringValue));
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Oops, not a number...");
                    }
                }
            }

            return numbers.Sum().ToString();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtOne" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding NumberOne}" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtTwo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding NumberTwo}" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtThree" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding NumberThree}" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,0">
            <TextBlock.Resources>
                <local:SumConverter x:Key="SumConverter"/>
            </TextBlock.Resources>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SumConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="TxtOne" />
                    <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="TxtTwo" />
                    <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="TxtThree" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Here's how it looks

[image: example]

Comment: Example: if i want caculator 1 value Textbox take from 5 textbox and show this textbox ? 
textbox =( textbox1 - textbox2) /textbox3  ?

Comment: That's exactly what the code I replied with should do. Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: in the SimpleMath class that is the sum of the other values, and bind that to the TextBox 
but i cant caculator  it
 EX: ( public double A => textbox1 +2  ; )

Comment: public double A => No1; can't do it

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the full code for both suggested solutions. It should show you how to bind the sum value.

Comment: but my data is uploaded from sql server so does it have any effect?

Comment: It shouldn't have any negative effects. As soon as you update the bound properties, the UI will update itself thanks to the `PropertyChanged` event. If this helped you, would you mind marking the answer as correct? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have set up the calculation program for the program, but now the problem is that I want to integrate the two classes together but it still is not compatible so you can help me!

code see :

Comment: Hi, I have set up the calculation program for the program, but now the problem is that I want to integrate the two classes together but it still is not compatible so you can help me!

Comment: code see : https://pastebin.com/AnKXHgvg?fbclid=IwAR3pEa1RjQrrvMNTq8wTfZNvmAwBJJehwf_6UoFK7h96lKSmpOZiatPGB9M

https://pastebin.com/qzPDwvzJ?fbclid=IwAR3dP3Ef3Lo2SSmk9sSLOzrCxy0tZC5Hczpl76SX8TmzdX2cFfr1RmWayhI